# Dotnetbar - Starting location of slide panel, slide in and slide out

Tags: vb.net, dotnetbar

when i click the button that trigger the slide panel to slide in, the slide in starts at the left side of the form, but what i want is for the slide panel to slide in at the left side of my panel, is it possible?

I've tried..

1. looking at the properties of the slide panel in case there's a properties for setting the start point of slide-in, but cant find one.

Comment: I've never used DotNetBar but, assuming that what you have works like a regular control, try adding it to your existing `Panel` instead of the form. You can see and modify the control hierarchy in the Document Outline window.

Comment: the slide panel also acts as a panel, so i just put the regular panel and slide panel on top of each other while the regular panel is at the back most, so its still the same T.T 

Thanks for answering tho. :D